# How to plot pandas dataframe in same figure without destroying their actual orientation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, twinx

I was trying to do a comparison of runtime between **Naive matrix multiplication** and **Strassen's**. For this, I was recording the runtime for a different dimension of the matrices. Then I was trying to plot the result in the same graph for the comparison.

But the problem is the plotting is not showing the proper result.

1. Here is the data...

   `2   3142
   3   3531
   4   4756
   5   5781
   6   8107`

The leftmost column is denoting `n`, the dimension and rightmost column is denoting execution time.

The above data is for **Naive method** and the data for **Strassen** is in this pattern too.

I'm inserting this data to a **pandas dataframe**. And after plotting the data the image looks like this:
[image]

Here blue is for **Naive** and green is for **Strassen's**
This is certainly not true as **Naive** cannot be constant. But my code was correct. SO I decided to plot them separately and these are the result:

**Naive**
[image: Naive]

**Strassen**
[image]

As you can see it might happen because the scaling in Y axis is not the same?
Is this the reason?

The code I'm implementing for plotting is:

```
fig = plt.figure()

data_naive = pd.read_csv('naive.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
data_naive.columns = ["n", "time"]
plt.plot(data_naive['n'], data_naive['time'], 'g')

data_strassen = pd.read_csv('strassen.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
data_strassen.columns = ["n", "time"]
plt.plot(data_strassen['n'], data_strassen['time'], 'b')

plt.show()

fig.savefig('figure.png')
```

What I tried to work out?

```
fig = plt.figure()

data_naive = pd.read_csv('naive.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
data_naive.columns = ["n", "time"]

data_strassen = pd.read_csv('strassen.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
data_strassen.columns = ["n", "time"]

ax = data_naive.plot(x='n', y='time', c='blue', figsize=(20,10))
data_strassen.plot(x='n', y='time', c='green', figsize=(20,10), ax=ax)

plt.savefig('comparison.png')
plt.show()
```

But no luck!!!

How to plot them in the same figure without altering their actual orientation?

Comment: The Strassen values are 1000 times higher (1e9 vs 1e7 on your graphs) which is why the naive method looks like a flat line in the first graph.

Comment: The two datasets are different by 2 orders of magnitude. So the question is; how would you like to plot them? Would you like to use two different scales? Would you like to normalize the values to show them on the same scale?

Comment: Which one is better for comparison? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: For comparing runtime, the graph you already have is pretty good. Or you can show that on a log scale (`plt.gca().set_yscale("log")`). For comparisson of the shape, two scales might be better, `ax2 = plt.gca().twinx()`.

Answer (score -1):

**IIUC:** Here is a solution using `twinx`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 100, (12,2)))
df[1] = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(12)*1000., size=1)[0]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(df[0], color='r')
#Plot the secondary axis in the right side
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df[1], color='k')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Result produced:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think I'll go with my segmented image. Anyway, I didn't give the downvote.